# Can't find the API being called in Tour of Heroes

Tags: angular, angular-tour-of-heroes

I am learning Angular. I am studying the angular.io/tutorial Tour of Heroes at https://stackblitz.com/angular/akkkxgnylgd. In `app/hero.service.ts`, there is this code:

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api

   constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService) { }

   /** GET heroes from the server */
   getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(heroes => this.log(`fetched heroes`)),
        catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
      );
  }
```

I was trying to investigate the call to `/api/heroes`. I turned on Chrome Developer Tools but could find no trace of any http calls to `/api/heroes`. How can I see the invocation of this URL?

Comment: chrome dev tools often only shows the last part of a path. Is there an entry in the network tab for /heroes?

Comment: I filtered with the string `api` and the few requests shown does not include any `api/heroes`.

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#simulate-a-data-server: *This tutorial sample mimics communication with a remote data server by using the In-memory Web API module.

After installing the module, the app will make requests to and receive responses from the HttpClient without knowing that the In-memory Web API is intercepting those requests, applying them to an in-memory data store, and returning simulated responses.*

Comment: Thanks!  (How do I close the question?)